# Numerical integration of a system of stiff ODEs starting at a singular point

Tags: numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

Good afternoon,

I have a system of $3$ highly non linear differential equations, which I have to integrate form a starting singular point $x^1=[1,1,1]$, and theoretically I have to arrive to an attractor $x^2$.

The problem comes when I try to integrate from a perturbed point $x^1 + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a random vector of norm little enough $10^{-10}$.
What I get is a set of solutions which go to infinity and do not go to the point $x^2$. And if a solution ever seems clearly to go to $x^2$, it diverges at some point of the path.

Any ideas?

P.D. The system depends on a parameter $M$. When $M=1.1$, it is less stiff, and I do manage to find a point near $x^1$ which goes and arrives to the exact theoretically predicted sink point. But when $M$ is $1.2$ or more, it gets SO stiff... any ideas are welcome :)
P.P.D. I have all analytical information possible: Jacobian at each point, etc.
P.P.P.D: Thanks for the editing and adding the "$" :D
The equations are:

$\dot{x}(1)=x(1)-1+\epsilon(x(3)-1)+\frac{1}{(\gamma M^2)}(\frac{x(2)}{x(1)}-1)$
$\dot{x}(2)=(\frac{2}{3}P(\gamma-1)M^2)(-(x(1)-1)^2+\epsilon(x(3)-2x(1)+1)(x(3)-1)+\frac{2}{\gamma(\gamma-1)M^2}(x(2)+(\gamma-1)x(1)-\gamma))$

$\dot{x}(3)=\frac{x(2)(x(1)-x(3))}{x(1)x(3)F}$

Where $P=0.67,F=17.79M^2,\gamma=\frac{5}{3},\epsilon=0.5,M\in(0,2)$ are parametres, all fixed.

As additional information, there are 2 positive eigenvalues and 1 negative at $x^1=[1,1,1]$. The ratio between the "spurious" eigenvalue and the good one (which leads to $x^2$) is: When M=1, 10. When M=1.1, 11. When M=1.2, 16. When M=1.4, 84. Etc.

The following images show how sensitive is the system to M, specifically the system integration from random points $10^{-10}$ away from $x_1$. In the first case, $M=1.2$, the right path is not found. In the second case, $M=1.1$, some points find the right path, and eventually one reaches $x^2$.

[image: Case M=1.2]

[image: Case M=1.1]

Comment: It might help if you gave us the actual equations.  You might be able to use asymptotic expansions near the singular point.

Comment: Let's suppose I have the asymptotic solution near the singular point. How would this help me? Thank you :)

Comment: Also, what integrator do you use?

Comment: I integrate using ode15s, Matlab's stiff equations solver. I hope it is powerful enough to carry out the work, and that the problem is choosing the right initial condition...

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you wrote that correctly?

You don't just have a singular point, you have a singular plane $x_1 = x_2$.
When you start close to a point on this plane (with $x_2 \ne 0$), $\dot{x_1}$ will be very large, either positive or negative depending on the sign of
$x_2/(x_2 - x_1)$.  Unfortunately, if $x_2 > 0$ the sign of this derivative is opposite to the sign of $x_1 - x_2$, thus $|x_1 - x_2|$ will decrease: solutions will head into the singular plane and cease to exist.  There are no solutions that leave the neighbourhood of $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Thank you, I had an errata. It is fixed. Now both $x_1$ (departure point) and $x_2$ (theoretical arrival (sink) point) are critical points

Comment: No idea of which strategy could work? :( Indeed if I could know in what direction starts the solution curve, I could sample efficiently and have more chances to find a good $x_0$ near $x_1$ to integrate from it, but this direction doesn't seem to be that of Jacobian's eigenvectors at $x_1$.

Comment: If your trajectory is going to be in the singular plane, you can treat that as a constraint: substitute $x_1 = x_2$ and have two nonsingular differential equations in the two unknowns $x_2, x_3$.

Comment: I know, but the solution trajectory is not in the singular plane. By the way, the "singularity" is gone, it was an errata. There are only critical points: The departure one, $x^1$ (and the final one, sink, $x^2$, which also is not in the plane $x_1=x_2$)

Comment: If you've made changes, you haven't let us in on the changes.  As far as I can see, $\dot{x}_1$ is still singular on $x_1 = x_2$,  the initial point $(1,1,1)$  is on that singular plane, and you haven't told us what the final point is supposed to be.

Comment: All my answers were to inform you about a (fixed) errata (quote: "I had an errata. It is fixed. Now both points (departure and arrival) are critical points"; quote: "singularity is gone, it was an errata. There are only critical points". On the other hand, as I have already stated, the departure AND the arrival/final point are critical points. It's enough to equal the equations to 0 to find it, but its expression is long (as the equations') and it does not give any useful information. Thirdly, I disagree: $x_1=x_2$ is not a singular plane for $\dot{x}_1$. But thank you anyway.

Comment: And you still won't tell us the actual corrected equations.  There's nothing more I can say about it.